# Add remote via JGit

Tags: java, git, jgit

I playing around JGit, I could successfully remove a remote from some repository (`git remote rm origin`), how can I do a `git remote add origin http://github.com/user/repo` ?

To remove I do the following:

```
StoredConfig config = git.getRepository().getConfig();
config.unsetSection("remote", "origin");
config.save();
```

But there's no a option like `#setSection(String, String)`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Managed it to work that way:

```
Git git = new Git(localRepository);
StoredConfig config = git.getRepository().getConfig();
config.setString("remote", "origin", "url", "http://github.com/user/repo");
config.save();
```

Comment: An instance of `Git`.

Comment: What is the equivalent git command?

Answer (score 1):

There are classes to add new ones:

```
    RemoteAddCommand remoteAddCommand = git.remoteAdd();
    remoteAddCommand.setName("origin");
    remoteAddCommand.setUri(new URIish("http://github.com/user/repo"));
    remoteAddCommand.call();
```

There is a `RemoteSetUrlCommand` too.

Comment: Available since jgit 4.2 for those like me using an antique version

Answer (score 0):

You can direct manipulate remote object with [git24j](https://github.com/git24j)

```
Repository repo = Repository.open("your-repository");
Remote upstream = Remote.create(repo, "upstream", URI.create("http://github.com/user/repo"));
```

and of cause you can also do the same thing through git-config APIs:

```
Config cfg = Config.openOndisk("my-git.config");
cfg.setString("remote.url", "http://github.com/user/repo");
```